# Можно ли shell скриптом получить данные из файла и выполнить команду

Tags: bash, shell, scripts

У меня есть пример файла test.json :

```
{
"q1":{
    "url1":"https://....."
},
"q2":{
    "url2":"https://....."
}
....
}
```

Можно ли в shell скрипте  указать данные какой переменной мне именно нужны и в зависимости от этого, сделать запуск уже второго скрипта с этими параметрами, чтобы в целом получилось вот примерно так:

```
"config": "sh -ac 'if test ФАЙЛ1 не пустой"; then cp ЗНАЧЕНИЕ_ИЗ_ФАЙЛА1 ФАЙЛ2; fi'"
"run_test": "cross-env ОКРУЖЕНИЕ=НУЖНОЕ_МНЕ_ЗНАЧЕНИЕ
 npm run config && .\\node_modules\\.bin\\wdio config\\wdio.chrome.headless.conf.js"
```

сам скрипт будет выполнять запуск тестов с разным окружением, эти 2 скрипта (config и run_test) находятся в файле package.json, config дополняет run_test, с помощью config'a мы можем создавать другие скрипты по типу run_test'a для разных окружений

и в итоге, в моем test.json находится 100 ссылок, которые я смогу указывать в скрипте на месте значения переменной "НУЖНОЕ_МНЕ_ЗНАЧЕНИЕ", обращаясь к имени переменных, которые эти ссылки содержат

заранее извиняюсь за возможную неграмотность в данном вопросе

Comment: [Отформатируйте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1312441/edit) ваш вопрос, что такое `"config"` и `"run_test"`? Если это не имеет отношения к данному вопросу, то удалите.

Comment: извлечь данные из json? [можно, конечно](https://github.com/ingydotnet/json-bash). только зачем?